# Javascript autocomplete current line and add {} curly braces?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, is there a way I can use keyboard combination like "ctrl+enter" to finish the current line and add { automatically at end of the line? instead of that i have to go to the end of the line my self and type { for it.

For example, when I typed if, VS code gives me if () blocks automatically, and I started typing condition in the braces.

```js
if (condition) 
// while the cursor is after 'n' but before ')'
```

When I'm at the end of the "condition", I have to use arrow key to move to the end and add {}. Do you program Javascript in this way or you have better tools/keyboard shortcut to use?

While I'm programming in Python, most IDE like VScode or Pycharm provides quick completion keyboard shortcut like "ctrl+shift+enter" to finish the line by adding ":" at end of the sentence, which applies to both defining functions, if, for, conditions. But unfortunately I haven't found such a way in Javascript world yet.

Answer (score 1):

Search for snippets on the VS extension section ,I think you can find it there for any programming language .

Comment: I have default vscode javascript snippets and prettier extension added. But not see they help in this case. Which snippets you suggest and what keyboard shortcut can trigger the autocompletion + move to new line in your case?

Comment: there is a couple of extensions :

-- JavaScript (ES6) code snippets

-- Beautify

-- Auto Close Tag

Answer (score 0):

1. Install this Visual Studio Code extension: [Complete Line](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=refactor11.completeline)
2. Press the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>